# Openlayers service displaced

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm working on QGIS with a shapefile (datum is ED50 or ETRS89). When adding the OpenLayers satellite service layer, it is displaced generating an error of about 2m from west to east, and doesn't have the required accuracy. I tried the same vector data in ArcGIS and I have no problem. Fits perfectly.

Any suggestions?

---

[image]

I don't know how to show any code.

Comment: Show some code and a screen shot, maybe? Hard to know from the  information provided.

Comment: Don't use EPSG:3857. Try using source datum.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean it's displaced in the print composer, I believe this is a known bug. Try using the Quick Map Services plugin instead, it seems to be free of this and other issues.